# Mailchimp embedded form font colour

Tags: css, wordpress, mailchimp

You can't see the text on my mailchimp form when a user tyypes it in because the font is dark and so is the background. Does anyone know how to change the font to white? Thanks https://www.caliberbio.com

Comment: You need to learn how to inspect code if you're going to be doing web design.  That's one of the most basic things.  Otherwise, you should probably look at hiring a qualified professional.

Comment: @JustinR. Dude honestly I looked for the code regarding the font color and I couldn't find it. Maybe you could help me and explain how I would solve this issue on my own? Ive never written code but I would like to learn how to solve problems like this on my own

Comment: Inspect the element in the browser.  Right click on the field and choose "Inspect".  You can see the related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following css rule into your theme's or child-theme's (active theme) css file (style.css).

```
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group input {
    color: white;
}
```